# How to match string if not a substring of another string?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to match a string only if it it's not a substring of another string.

Example:

```
I need to find if text contains string "bbbb" that is not part of a string "aaaabbbbcccc".
```

Regular expression should match strings:

```
aaabbbbcccc
aaaabbbbccc
aaabbbbccc
bbbbcccc
aaaabbbb
```

but not match:

```
aaaabbbbcccc
```

I've tried to do this with lookarounds:

```
(?<!aaaa)bbbb(?!cccc)
```

but it doesn't work. It matches only

```
aaabbbbccc
```

Comment: Why match `aaabbbccc`? Only 3 `b` in it.

Comment: Using PHP. And yes, there is a typo, it should be aaabbbbccc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both assertions have to be true, if you use it your way. Use an alternation to make it only fail if both assertions are failing, but not when only one is failing.

```
(?<!aaaa)bbbb|bbbb(?!cccc)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31qmc)

I assume your third example should also have four "b".

Answer (score 0):

if you do this:

```
.{0,4}b{4}.{0,4}
```

and then this:

```
a{4}b{4}c{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print if /bbbb/ && $_!~/aaaabbbbcccc/ ' your_input
```